# How to display a value with zenity?

Tags: bash, sh, zenity

I'm trying to calculate Euler's numb. but I'm having problems trying to display the result. This is what I have:

```
#Using a switch an case

"Euler's Number")
szAnswer=$(zenity --info --text "Enter a number")
result = "(1+1/$szAnswer)^$szAnswer" | bc -l
zenity --info --text "Euler's Numb: $result"
```

I'm able to input a number and all, but when it comes to giving me the output result it just stays blank. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `result = "(1+1/$szAnswer)^$szAnswer" | bc -l` line. It reads:

- execute command `result` with parameters `=` and `"(1+1/$szAnswer)^$szAnswer"`
- connect the `stdout` stream of the `result` command to `bc` command's `stdin` stream

Probably you're wondering why `result` is a command in this case. That's because variable assignments in shell scripting are made without spaces separating variable name and assigned value. You also want to send `"(1+1/$szAnswer)^$szAnswer"` to `stdin` of `bc -l` command,so you need something capable of writing to `stdout`

What should be done is

```
result=$( echo "(1+1/${szAnswer})^${szAnswer}" | bc -l )`
```

Now you have `result` variable being assigned output of `echo "(1+1/${szAnswer})^${szAnswer}" | bc -l` pipeline. The `$(...)` structure is called command substitution, and is generally used when command's output has to be reused in place of the command itself.

Comment: For bash, a here string would be another option: `result=$(bc -l <<< "(1+1/$szAnswer)^$szAnswer")`

Comment: Yes,  here-string would probably be even more preferable for `ksh` and `bash`

Comment: TBH I hadn't even noticed the `sh` tag ...

Comment: @steeldriver  It's negligible since there's a high chance OP is using `bash` and since they haven't shown the full script.

Comment: Thank you for the help and also for explaining how are things being executed.

Comment: @escobarveras You're welcome. Happy scripting !